# What is the best way to check if the "Admin" Group is in the user groups (using has_and_belong_to_many relationships) in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dev-to-production

I just want to check if the "Admin" Group is in the user groups. User and Group model has a has_and_belong_to_many relationship.

I had the system working fine with rails in developer mode, but when I tried to pass to production, this line in my "game" controller did not work:

```
   if current_user.groups.where(:name => "Admin") != []

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Table 'db_production.groups' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `groups`)
```

Also, the same query works fine in the rails console:

```
irb(main):001:0> User.find(1).groups.where(:name =>
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`i
  Group Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `groups`.* FROM `groups` INNER JOIN `groups_users` ON `groups`.`id` = `groups_users`.`group_id` WHERE `groups_users`.`user_id` = 1 AND `groups`.`name` = 'Admin'
=> false
```

The server has Rails 3.2.0 and uses Phusion Passenger version 3.0.11 with Apache. I use device gem for the user management.

Comment: Did you migrate the database in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear from the error message that `groups` table does not exist in `db_production` database.

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'db_production.groups doesn't exist
```

Probably your migration might have failed in production server.